# how do you send an escape key stroke to excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

After I cut and paste columns to a log worksheet the copy selection borders remain. Manually clicking escape gets rid of them. How can I get rid of them in the macro code? Escape key is not recorded by macro recorder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to send the <kbd>Esc</kbd> keystroke for this. Simply add this line after the paste command.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```